# How should I model the wing membrane of my character's wings?

Tags: modeling, texturing, rigging

I'm not sure if I should model the wing membrane as a flat plane or if I should solidify it. I want a very thin membrane for the wings, but I don't know if I'll be able to use a flat plane. Does somebody know if modeling them in this way will mess up the texturing, rigging, ect.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use a single face unless you absolutely have to. This could cause a lot of trouble later on.

Comment: I didn't think it would work, but I didn't know. Thank you.